# Перекодировка части текста в data.frame из utf8 в win1251 в R

Tags: utf-8, r, перекодировка, ansi

Есть объект `data` в формате `data.frame`, который содержит столбцы с текстом в сочетании с другими данными, часть текста нормально отображается в UTF-8, часть текста кракозябрами в win-1251.

Например, столбец `data$attribute_3` содержит 500000 строк в UTF-8 и 300000 в win-1251.

Нужно ту часть текста, которая в UTF-8 перезаписать в кодировке win-1251. Часть данных с кодировкой win-1251 не трогать.

Как определить кодировку текста в R, чтобы отделить одно от другого, не нашел вообще никаких указаний.

`Data` берется из файла, в котором уже часть текста в UTF-8 часть в win-1251, так что читать данные из файла с `encoding=UTF-8` не вариант.

Проблема только в том, чтобы определить где в `data` кончаются  неправильно прочитанные в кодировке UTF-8 символы, закодированные в win-1251, которые отображаются как кракозябры. Перекодировать не проблема.

`(Encoding(data$attribute_3))` везде выдаёт UTF-8.

UPD: `stringi::stri_enc_detect` и `stringi::stri_enc_detect2` определяют весь текст как UTF-8 с вероятностью 1.

UPD:

> Encoding(data$attribute_3[1])

[1] "UTF-8"

> Encoding(data$attribute_3[813590])

[1] "UTF-8"

> data$attribute_3[1]

LABEL: fo
VALUES:
РЎРёР±РёСЂСЊ

> data$attribute_3[813590]

LABEL: fo
VALUES:
Волга

> t=iconv(data$attribute_3[1],from="utf8",to="cp1251")
> t1=iconv(data$attribute_3[1],from="cp1251",to="utf8")

> t

LABEL: fo
VALUES:
РЎРёР±РёСЂСЊ

> t1

LABEL: fo
VALUES:
Р РЋР С‘Р В±Р С‘РЎР‚РЎРЉ

> str(t)

Class 'labelled' chr "РЎРёР±РёСЂСЊ"
.. .. LABEL: fo

> str(t1)

Class 'labelled' chr "Р РЋР С‘Р В±Р С‘РЎР‚РЎРЉ"
.. .. LABEL: fo

Answer (score 1):

> Например, столбец data$attribute_3 содержит 500000 строк в UTF-8 и 300000 в win-1251

дальше исхожу из предположения, что в одной строке кодировки не смешаны, и каждая строка представляет собой либо `utf8`, либо `cp1251`.

---

для определения строки в кодировке *utf8* можно воспользоваться, например, функцией [`Encoding()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/Encoding) из пакета *base*:

```r
Encoding("строка")
#> [1] "UTF-8"
Encoding(iconv("строка", from="utf8", to="cp1251"))
#> [1] "unknown"
```

соответственно для перекодирования можно воспользоваться такой функцией:

```r
перекодирование1 <- function(x){ifelse(Encoding(x)=="UTF-8",iconv(x,from="utf8",to="cp1251"),x)}
```

применение её к таблице:

```r
d <- data.frame(s=c("строка1",iconv("строка2",to="cp1251")))
d
#>                           s
#> 1                   строка1
#> 2 \xf1\xf2\xf0\xee\xea\xe02
```

даст нужный результат:

```r
apply(d, 2, перекодирование1)
#>      s                          
#> [1,] "\xf1\xf2\xf0\xee\xea\xe01"                  
#> [2,] "\xf1\xf2\xf0\xee\xea\xe02"
```

---

другой вариант основывается на соображении, что при попытке перекодирования из `utf8` уже перекодированной в `cp1251` строки мы получим `NA`:

```r
iconv(iconv("строка", from="utf8", to="cp1251"), from="utf8", to="cp1251")
#> [1] NA
```

соответственно функция перекодирования может быть такой:

```r
перекодирование2 <- function(x) {c<-iconv(x,from="utf8",to="cp1251");ifelse(is.na(c),x,c)}
apply(d, 2, перекодирование2)
#>      s                          
#> [1,] "\xf1\xf2\xf0\xee\xea\xe01"
#> [2,] "\xf1\xf2\xf0\xee\xea\xe02"
```

---

обновление1. пример удачного перекодирования:

```
x <- iconv('сибирь', from='cp1251', to='utf8')
x
#> [1] "СЃРёР±РёСЂСЊ"
iconv(x, from='utf8', to='cp1251')
#> [1] "сибирь"
```

обновление2. для устранения последствий «двойного перекодирования», когда часть строк и так была в кодировке `utf8`, но к ним было применено преобразование `cp1251→utf8`, типа такого:

```
iconv("сибирь",to="utf8",from="cp1251")
#> [1] "СЃРёР±РёСЂСЊ"
```

а часть строк, которая изначально была в кодировке `cp1251`, была корректно преобразована, и в результате получился вот такой винегрет:

```
t <- data.frame(s=c('сибирь',iconv('сибирь',to='utf8',from='cp1251')))
t
#>              s
#> 1       сибирь
#> 2 СЃРёР±РёСЂСЊ
```

можно применить вот такую функцию:

```
перекодирование3 <- function(x) {c<-iconv(iconv(x,from="utf8",to="cp1251"),from="utf8",to="cp1251");ifelse(is.na(c),x,iconv(x,from="utf8",to="cp1251"))}
apply(t, 2, перекодирование3)
#>      s       
#> [1,] "сибирь"
#> [2,] "сибирь"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116046/discussion-on-answer-by-aleksandr-barakin-----data-fram).